# What's happening in the line of code? How its executing without any issues

Tags: c#-4.0

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Action<int, int> ActionDelegate = new Action<int, int>(add);
        http://csharpstar.com   
        ActionDelegate.Invoke(130, 45);
  }
```

I would like how this above piece of code is execute without any issue?
Can you someone provide the reason behind this?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Yes is you are right!!. But this is piece of code executing with any issues. Please dont give downvote

Comment: @ThangamaniPalanisamy: I didn't downvote

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

`http:` is interpreted as a `goto` label and `//csharpstar.com` is a comment.